nuget push to github with "NotFound" result
I've just this error when trying to upload NuGet package to GitHub. I enter following as usual
dotnet nuget push ... --source "https://nuget.pkg.github.com/CNCProfi/index.js"
and get this result:
  PUT https://nuget.pkg.github.com/CNCProfi/index.js/
  NotFound https://nuget.pkg.github.com/CNCProfi/index.js/ 465ms
error: Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found)

The message is the same as in this Unable to push github package for nuget (404) but it's closed and I've wasted almost 3h on this before finding solution so I want to share it.

I don't know what broked this but I've removed the index.js part and it worked. Basically:
dotnet nuget push ... --source "https://nuget.pkg.github.com/CNCProfi/"
And it's fine:
  PUT https://nuget.pkg.github.com/CNCProfi/
  OK https://nuget.pkg.github.com/CNCProfi/ 971ms
Your package was pushed.

